# How can I pass through request body when using API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I deployed a REST api gateway on AWS and enabled "Use HTTP Proxy integration" to pass all requests to a http endpoint. It works fine for `GET` with path parameters. But it doesn't pass through all BODY in POST request. How can I make it to pass everything to downstream http endpoint?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't pass through all BODY"? So its only part of the body that goes through - its truncated?

Comment: I mean the body in the POST request is not pass through

Comment: body should be passed through to backend http endpoint, json body will be stringified and will be as `body` as given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html#api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda-test)